# Symmetric Covariance operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I would like to ask if we can generalise that whenever we have a symmetric covariance operator on a Hilbert space then we can say that it's self-adjoint (because of the symmetry)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to prove whether the covariance operator is self-adjoint? Because this is indeed true, and shouldn't be hard to prove by just using the definition of adjoint and the covariance operator.

Comment: No no , I just wanted to know if this assumption is right , because on the notes that I read right now , they just mention it as example and I wasn't sure if we can generalise it.But thank you !!